# How to use mail function in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried mail function in laravel but i did not get success.Kindly suggest me that how to send email in laravel.
here is my code in Controller.

```
 $Body = "$CusName ($UID - $CusEmail ) from $SiteID";

 $param = array('User'=>$Use, 'Pass'=>$Pass,'Body'=>$Body,'SiteID'=>$SiteID);
 $Email['To']="xyz@gmail.com";
 $Email['Sender']=$CusEmail;
 $Email['Body']=$data;

 $mail= mail("xyz@gmail.com","My subject",$data);
```

Thankyou

Comment: How is that supposed to work? $param is not used, $data is not defined

Answer (score 5):

You should not be using **mail()** function directly with Laravel. Instead, use the **Mail** facade to send emails using any of available drivers.

```
Mail::send('your.view', $arrayOfParameterPassedToTheView, function ($m) {
  $m->from('from@email.com', 'Topic');
  $m->to('to@email.com', 'User Name')->subject('Subject');
});
```

You can find more examples here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/using-sparkpost-for-transactional-emails-with-laravel) post sending mail. And most importantly laravel default mail system mailtrap is for local environment only you can't send mail using mailtrap from server. Using sparkpost you can send 100,000 mail free per day.Its easy to setup and send mail almost instant.